# How safe is it to use deprecated Windows API?

Tags: xps

The Microsoft **XPS Print API** exists to print XPS documents. Within MSDN the API is marked with various notes saying things like:

- *The APIs described in this section are deprecated. Client applications should use the Print Document Package API instead.*
- *IXpsPrintJob is not supported and may be altered or unavailable in the future.*

The APIs were introduced at Windows 7 but are marked as "End of Client Support" at Windows 8.1

However, using ILSpy, it looks as though System.Printing is implemented in terms of the XPS Print API, so the use of the XPS Print API is and will always be part of .NET.

I'd be interested to know why end-users would be warned off using this API whilst MS are quite happy to use it from within .NET  Any suggestions?

Comment: *"so the use of the XPS Print API is and will always be part of .NET"* That would be always as in "until they refactor it to use a different API".